# why XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onerror doesn't work in synchronous request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronization

i tried the [XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror) to deal if the request failed but it works only in Asynchronous request .. while i do need an sync request cause it makes the code a lot easier for me and works on order .
the code

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'http://192.168.1.2/';
http.open('get', url, false ); 



  http.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(http.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(http.status === 200)
            {

console.log("it worked ")

            }

        }
    }

   http.onerror = function () {
  console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
  };


http.send();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvuRD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just turn it back to aync(true) and fix the rest of the code using callbacks !